# Split String differently under different conditions

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying the following: `public static Element parse(String input) {`
gets a String as an input and has to determine if the input either is a fraction or an operator.
This is one example:

> sin(x) + (1/x) / x + 7

My code already checks if there is the same amount of opening and closing parenthesis, as well as if there always is a numerator and a denominator if there is a fraction submitted.

Now I've got a problems:
1. A new Fraction element should be created if there is a "/" present in the String that is not surrounded by parenthesis. In the example above, sin(x) + (1/x) would be the numerator and x + 7 would be the denominator. I don't really have any idea how to split the String according to this.

[Final Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAzzU.png)

Help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: you are aware of conditional statements?

Comment: Wouldn't BEDMAS dictate that the expression would be sin(x) + [(1/x) / x] + 7? It seems like more brackets are needed in general for clarity.

Comment: I am aware of those, yes. Only problem is that I'm not sure how to build a correct if-statement for this. What the if statement basically would need to do is to check which dash has the lowest precedence and split the string accordingly.

Comment: @Kevin The final output would be sth like (see above)

Comment: I'd tokenize the string first to get an array of its elements `["sin". "(", "x", ")", "+", "(","1", "/", "x", ")" ,"/", "x", "+", '7']` and then I'd build parser that consumes such array and decide what is denomimator.
`

Comment: As @Kevin pointed out, your approach is wrong. String should look like `[sin(x) + (1/x)] / (x + 7)`. You have to define the way your math strings are build, and then split...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should maybe put your String into a charArray which is easier to deal with at some point.

What I would do then is taking the charArray in a for loop which counts up or down based on the average lenght of your numberator and denominator. You count on the one hand the numbers of opened parenthesis and on the other hand you look for "/" and if parenthesis is 0 you count this as a numerator...

Ok now in Code.

```
public static Element parse(String s) {
     // ...
     char[] c = s.toCharArray();
     int brackets = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < c.length(); i++) {
          if (c[i] == '(') brackets++;
          else if (c[i] == ')') brackets--;
          else if (c[i] == '/' && brackets == 0) return new FractionElement();
     }
     // ...
     return new OperatorElement();
}
```

Hope I was able to help you ;) Had a similar problem recently...

PS: If you want to split the numerator and the denominator into 2 substrings just do this:

```
//...
else if (c[i] == '/' && brackets == 0) {
      String numerator = s.substring(0, i);
      String denominator = s.substring(i+1, s.length);
}
//...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this sounds promising. I'll try to get this into the context!